# Does silent install of Tableau Server 10.2 on AWS EC2 instance work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, tableau-api, aws-cloudformation

I am working on infrastructure automation using Ansible scripts. I installed Tableau Server 10.2 on EC2 instance manually. It requires you to accept terms and asks for registration. Out of the box Tableau doesn't support silent install, at least I didn't find anything on their forums. Has anyone tried automating the installation of Tableau Server?

Comment: Look at http://github.com/Tableau. There are some server install examples that might be useful

Comment: Thank you Alex. I found the same on AWS as well. I am looking into the scripts. https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/tableau-server/

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the Quickstart CloudFormation scripts that Tableau and AWS have posted here: [Quickstart URL](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-tableau-server).

They have a windows single machine install and a cluster, both of which use a python script to do the silent install. If your looking for the Linux setup, their is a branch with a CloudFormation that does a linux install on a single server.

If your Tableau install requires AD, the documentation out there will say that the [Quickstart](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/tableau-server/) doesn't support it.  However, if you check out the config.yml file used in the quick start and the documentation [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/entity_identity_store.htm) it appears you can put in the AD configuration you need in the json file.

In your script, post install, you'll want to copy your backup configuration from s3, and perform a [restore](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/db_restore.htm) using the `tabadmin restore backupFile`. Most of what the CloudFormation does should be useable in Ansible.